# Do current EU treaties allow any discussions ("reinterpretations") of Treaty of Trianon?

Tags: european-union, treaty, hungary

[This article](http://hungarianspectrum.org/tag/little-entente/) comments upon a public speech held by János Lázár (Minister of Prime Minister's Office):

> “The Hungarian nation should receive if not material at least moral
>   reparations for the greatest injustice in world history.” He added
>   that “we don’t want any change of the borders and especially not
>   ethnic tension … new wars in Europe … but that doesn’t mean that we
>   will tolerate the provocations, the repeated violations of our
>   national sensibility for another 100 years. Yes, we can say even now:
>   “Justice for Hungary!” which was the cry for revision after 1929.
>
> I strongly suspect that these new words were not born in the heat of a
>   fiery nationalistic speech. The Orbán government seems to have decided
>   to open another front in its war against Europe, this time for a
>   reinterpretation of the Treaty of Trianon. This is a serious turn of
>   events that may not bode well for peace in the region.

The transcript of the speech can be found [here](http://www.kormany.hu/hu/miniszterelnokseg/hirek/lazar-janos-miniszterelnokseget-vezeto-miniszter-beszede-szarvas) (Hungarian) and it is also referenced by a [Romanian news site](http://www.hotnews.ro/stiri-international-21803579-janos-lazar-seful-cabinet-premierului-ungar-viktor-orban-mesaj-catre-bruxelles-comemorarea-trianonului-nu-vom-tolera-incalcarile-repetate-ale-sensibilitatilor-noastre-nationale-pentru-inca-100-ani.htm).

**Question:** considering current EU treaties, is any discussion regarding the [Treaty of Trianon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Trianon) possible?

Comment: Do you mean regarding war reparations, or regarding land borders?

Comment: @origimbo - I was thinking about both. But if this makes the question too broad, "war reparations" is enough, as I know there is a treaty or something similar that stipulates that the borders are fixed within EU.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there isn't : http://www.politico.eu/article/belgium-and-netherlands-in-land-swap/

Comment: @origimbo - oh, this is interesting. Anyway, this was a very elegant border change.

Comment: I think the key is not renegotiation of treaties (which would be a matter concerning only the affected states) but the need to respect the principle of territorial integrity (Hungary cannot get land from another country without that country permission).

Comment: "Discussions" are always possible. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - yes, it is an ambiguous word. I am thinking about official discussions like within EU Parliament, but I could not find a better term. I will search for something more precise.

Comment: I don't think EU treaties have any bearing on this. Conversely, I see no reason for the EU parliament to get involved.